# Design Patterns for object creation with properties that can be const or non-const

Tags: c++, class, constants, instantiation

Consider the following object with 1 member variable and 2 constructors.

```
MyObject {
  const [or not] HasAnotherObject *m_pOtherObject;

  MyObject(HasAnotherObject *pOtherObject);
  MyObject(const HasAnotherObject *pOtherObject);
}
```

I want to instantiate a non-const and a const MyObject. The member variable must also have the same const status as the local variable.

```
MyObject myObjectVolatile(HasAnotherObject *pOtherObject);
const MyObject myObjectConst(const HasAnotherObject *pOtherObject);
```

However, the Class template must specify the const status irrelevant of the instantiation method.

Is there a design pattern that can help here?

Comment: `propagate_const`?

Comment: currently I use this solution:
one non-const member variable: `HasAnotherObject *m_pOtherObject`
and 2 methods:
    const HasAnotherObject hasAnotherObject() const {} and
    HasAnotherObject hasAnotherObject() {}
and 2 constructors with const and non-const options. The const one must do an unpleasant conversion to remove the const.

Comment: hi Nicky! thanks! i looked up propagate_const. got it. this solution uses C++ templates which is one of things i was considering. it adds considerable complexity to the class definition. but maintains pure and correct implementation.

it would be another option to use templates directly i would suggest:

    const MyObject<const HasAnotherObject>()

The issue there of course is that you would always need to match the template with the local variable const.

Comment: Nicky: could you "answer the question" with propagate_const also?

Comment: No, I can't. I only know it exist. I have not studied it. I am not capable of giving an answer.

Answer (score 0):

external suggestion:
one non-const member variable:

```
HasAnotherObject *m_pOtherObject
```

and 2 methods:

```
const HasAnotherObject hasAnotherObject() const {return m_pOtherObject;}
HasAnotherObject hasAnotherObject() {return m_pOtherObject;}
```

and 2 constructors:

```
MyObject(HasAnotherObject *pOtherObject): m_pOtherObject(pOtherObject) {}
MyObject(const HasAnotherObject *pOtherObject): m_pOtherObject((HasAnotherObject *) pOtherObject) {}
```

with const and non-const options. The const constructor must do an unpleasant conversion to remove the const

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the `const` is part of the type of a variable -- therefore you could have asked the same question with `int` and `double`. And the answer to both questions would be now, there is no design pattern or language feature to do what you want. Otherwise, the type `MyObject` would be unequal to it itself, and the "actual type" would be specified only by its instantiation. This *has to be* a highly unwanted behaviour.

So you (i) either have to rely on class templates (which you ruled out, presumably because you want to store objects of `MyObject` in a container). (ii) Or you should use a variant (this seems the best alternative to me). (iii) Or type-erase away the type `HasAnotherObject`. (iv) Or, similarly, you can use inheritance. (v) or possibly use further alternatives, but all will have their shortcomings.

Comment: agreed. I would say that const has differences though. for example:
int returnMyMemberVariable()

Comment: agreed!

`int returnMyMemberVariable() and long returnMyMemberVariable()`

and

`const Thing returnMyMemberVariable() const and Thing returnMyMemberVariable()`

are interestingly different.

in the second example, the const status of the local pointer affects the vtable method that is run on the referenced object. that doesn't help us with the fact that you have rightly pointed out that these 2 objects with different const status of member variables SHOULD be 2 different Classes. Or use templates in some way like propagate_const

Comment: @AnnesleyNewholm: afaik `propagate_const`does not help here, as it solves the problem that `const` class members can call non-const members of the pointee. If you want to make a point here, I would suggest to simply drop the `const` in front of `HasAnotherObject *`. Instead, make it a private member and treat it accordingly in the functions of your class. The idea behind is that `const` variables can be of reduced usefulness (--why constrain yourself?). Rather make it non-const and be careful in the handling.

Comment: well, you have opened an enormous philosophical question there!!! which would be naughty to debate here. but i can't resist:

i love C++. The reason I love it is because I can very very clearly and colourfully describe the intended purpose of the methods, classes and structures that I create. I have a bad memory, I work in a team and I work on security code. I want const things to be const and everyone, including me to know that the intended purpose was const, private, protected, etc.

`propagate_const` works only as much as the instantiator uses the correct associated template argument.

Comment: @AnnesleyNewholm: I understand, and I see it quite similarly. But there are often situations in C++ where the optimal solution is a balance between different requirements. Consider your case, and let's say you want to store your class in a container. For this you could inherit two classes, one with a const pointer and the other without, and create a common base class interface -- where you then basically can expose only the const methods. In the end, you gain nothing but complexity. You could have the same by using a single class with a non-const pointer and exposing only const methods.